# Animation conflict in game engine

Tags: animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am just making a simple spaceship in game engine, I want the ship to bank as it moves left or right.

I added two animations to the key presses and this works fine, however, if both keys <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> are hit at the same time the animations completely break.

It is difficult to explain exactly what I mean, so here's the .blend  [image]

I must be missing something obvious here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your file in BGE and UPBGE.

The bug still persists in BGE but seems completely fixed in UPBGE.

## Commit Proof

https://github.com/UPBGE/upbge/commit/d05cb9bca5654a621a9daf7547fa031ab467ef85

https://github.com/UPBGE/upbge/commit/bd8f4cc4d6de396c902ee47261baba11bdd8f0a1